# What is Samsung galaxy tab 10.1 usable screen resolution?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab-10, screen-resolution

The screen is 1280 x 800 pixels but the system bar uses up some of the vertical height.
So what is the screen resolution minus the black system bar at the bottom?

This is needed to configure an RDP client to exact screen dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My testing indicates a usable resolution of 1280 x 750